# Subset data frame by multiple sets of indicies

Tags: r, subset

If I have a data frame like this:

```
    x <- data.frame(col1 = rep(2,10),col2 = rep(3,10)
       ,col3 = rep(2,10),col4 = rep(3,10),col5 = rep(2,10)
       ,col6 = rep(3,10),col7 = rep(2,10),col8 = rep(3,10))

    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
1     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
2     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
3     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
4     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
5     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
6     2    3    2    3    2    3    2    3
```

And I want to get the column names for col 1-4 and 6-8.
In other words something like this:

```
colnames(x[1:4,6:8])
```

how can I do that?

Comment: `colnames(x[, c(1:4,6:8)])` or better `names(x[c(1:4, 6:8)])`

Comment: that was easy...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
colnames(x)[c(1:4,6:8)]
#[1] "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col6" "col7" "col8"
```